# Getting screen width value in a PHP variable using Ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I'm trying to get the screen width in a PHP variable via Ajax request.

JS file:

```
function screen() {
    var xmlhttp;
    var sWidth=window.screen.width;
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "screen.php?width="+sWidth, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
window.onload=screen();
```

PHP file:

```
<?PHP 
$screen=$_GET["width"];
echo $screen;
?>
```

But at the end it shows that undefined 'width'. Help

Comment: FYI: the viewable portion of the browser window is called the `viewport`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var sWidth = window.screen.width;
alert("sWidth is: " + sWidth);
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "screen.php?width=" + sWidth;
xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xhttp.onload = function() { 
    alert("Result: " + xhttp.responseText); 
};
alert("Sending: " + url);
xhttp.send(null);
```

Seems to work fine. No problems in FF or IE9 http://jsfiddle.net/JsHaw/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var sWidth=window.innerWidth;
```

[docs here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.innerWidth)

Hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
function screen() {
    var xmlhttp;
    var sWidth=window.innerWidth;

    if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "screen.php?width="+sWidth, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
window.onload=screen();
```